# MPMoviePlayerController won't load an HTTP audio stream

Tags: ios, http-streaming

I'm trying to use an MPMoviePlayerController on iOS to play back an audio stream over HTTP.

I've imported `MediaPlayer.framework` and used the code from [MPMoviePlayerController's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but I get no sound.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://shoutmedia.abc.net.au:10326"]];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.view addSubview: player.view];

[player play];
```

I've also tried adding `player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;` but didn't work neither.

Any thoughts?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController for audio stream ???

Comment: From the first line of [MPMoviePlayerController's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html): "A movie player (of type MPMoviePlayerController) manages the playback of a movie from a file or a network stream."

Comment: But you are not playing movie, you said audio stream. Look at AVAudioPlayer if you want to play from file in memory. Since you want it streaming look at https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Comment: Wait, so there's a class to stream a movie but nothing to stream an audio file???